# angular2 ngFor doesn't generate an exception when the collection is undefined

Tags: angular

I have a ngFor attribute on an html tag as follow:

```
<li *ngFor="let x of collection">....</li>
```

If i make a typo in the collection, say i write it collections, no exception is generated saying collections is undefined and the code executes properly.

Is there a way to generate an exception when such problem occur?

Comment: On the template side, the closest to generating an exception would be to display an error message. <div *ngIf="collection.length == 0">Error!</div>

Comment: If you use a helper function -- let's say, `getCollection()`, in your component, that returns the said collection -- then if you make a typo in the function name, you get your exception. That's the closest to getting an exception I am aware of.